# Wordpress customize page doesn't work due to load-scripts.php error

Tags: php, wordpress

Due to plugin conflict(i guess), customize.php page doesn't load properly. It stops while loading and only widget and theme name appear on the left. I'm using DIVI and all was working fine before configuring Favicon by RealFaviconGenerator. **Even half an hour after setting favicon all worked fine**. So I don't know exactly if it's a plugin conflict.
Console says that load-scripts.php goes in error: **f.state is not a function**.
I unistalled the plugin and deleted the favicon but it's stille the same.

Thanks in advance

[screenshot of page and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK0Bg.png)

Comment: Can you please try to deactivate all the plugins one by one and check ?

Comment: I tried. Customize section still doesn't work.